# How Can I Get In Cloud Service "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Role"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I have only "web role" without the MVC ? how can i add an option for ASP.NET MVC 4 web role ?

I would like to follow those examples and i cant because i don't have this option:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/working-with-azure-blob-storage-in-mvc/

and this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77JMd49Va_g&index=7&list=PLpSms-ovawn4aC8Wx6rLQVravCq-CUuOq

I cant follow because they start a cloud project and than they choose "MVC 4 Web Role" and i have only "Web Role" so i cant proceed with this example..What can i do ?

Comment: Azure WebRole Project is responsible for **deployment**, you first create it (regardless of the later-to-be-associated project) then associate a web project to it, be it an MVC or WebForms project.

Comment: Haim i'm follow on this tutorial :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/working-with-azure-blob-storage-in-mvc/

and this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77JMd49Va_g&index=7&list=PLpSms-ovawn4aC8Wx6rLQVravCq-CUuOq

And i cant follow because they start a cloud project and than they choose "MVC 4 Web Role" and i have only "Web Role" so i cant proceed with this example..What can i do ?

Comment: Do you already have an existing web project?

Comment: Yeah, but i got mixed up so i want to start fresh with those two example(and i cant because i dont have the MVC web role option, on the cloud services) and get the idea separately than implement it on my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ron,

If you have the already existing Cloud Service Visual Studio project, you can right click at the project's 'Roles' node in the solution explorer, add a new 'web role project', specify asp.net web role and select MVC at the next page in the project creation wizard.

Simon.